# My RecyclerView Adapter is not respond to updates via Volley Request?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, observable, android-volley

When I start my Application an Initial Message from a ChatBot should be displayed but isn't. It starts with a Volley Request that is successful and Data are there Imidially.

Then this is called in the Response Handler:

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        String[] text = ((JSONObject) response.get(i)).getString("text").split("'");
                        chat.addChat(new ChatBubbleModel(ChatBubbleModel.UserType.BOT, text[1]));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
```

The `chat` Property is a Property of Type `ChatModel` which is created with a Observer Pattern that triggers this UI Updates via a `RecyclerView.Adapter` Custom Implementation:

```
chat.observe(new ChatModel.Observer<ChatBubbleModel>() {

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChatBubbleModel data) {
                chatAdapter.addBubble(data);
                if (data.getUserType() == ChatBubbleModel.UserType.BOT) {
                    return;
                }
                    JSONObject requestInstance = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        requestInstance.put("text", data.getMessage());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }

                    CustomRequest request = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://url.com", requestInstance, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    String[] text = ((JSONObject) response.get(i)).getString("text").split("'");
                                    chat.addChat(new ChatBubbleModel(ChatBubbleModel.UserType.BOT, text[1]));
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }


                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> headers = Maps.newHashMap();
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            if (chat.getHistoryId() == null || chat.getHistoryId().isEmpty())
                                chat.setHistoryId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                            headers.put("historyID", chat.getHistoryId());
                            headers.put("userName", "");
                            headers.put("configurationId", "5ed0d05b95b0ba16f9690d31");
                            return headers;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQue.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
                }

        });
```

But shomehow all request inside this from the Bot (Chat Bubble Rendering) is only changed if I f.e expand Keyboard, so I think a RecyclerView Rerendering is triggered then, because of Size Change.

And this is the Method in My RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public void addBubble(ChatBubbleModel bubble) {
        this.bubbles.add(bubble);
        notifyItemChanged(bubbles.size() - 1);
    }
```

But if they are called on after the Volley Network Response the 
`public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` and `public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` methods aren't called. Only after the KeyBoard thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `notifyItemInserted(bubbles.size() - 1);` instead of  `notifyItemChanged(bubbles.size() - 1);`

Your `addBubble` method will be as follows :

```
public void addBubble(ChatBubbleModel bubble) {
        this.bubbles.add(bubble);
        notifyItemInserted(bubbles.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: I'll try that fix in a minute, hope it's the fix  But I'm sure I exposed myself as an Android Noob already 

Comment: That was actually the issue